# UDTF generates Cursor SQL_TABLE_CURSOR not open

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

#### Background:

We have two IBMi DB2 database environments, which I'll call DEV and PRODUCTION.  In most cases, we have duplicate tables although the dev data is neither maintained nor authoritative.

In production, we have a table that is updated from a third party source, that I don't want to take the time to maintain in development.  But I do need the updated information in development.

#### Attempted Solution:

So I had the bright idea of

1. Make a UDTF (User Defined Table Function) in dev to cross over the databases (using 3-part name), returning Production data in a Development function.
2. Make a view in dev with the same name as the production table, using the UDTF as its source.

When I `select * from myschema.myview`, in development, everything is hunky-dory.  I get results quickly.

But if I add a simple `where` clause to it, `select * from myschema.myview where id='1234'`, It hangs and then responds with

> [Code: -501, SQL State: 24501]  [SQL0501] Cursor SQL_TABLE_CURSOR not open.

---

After further testing, I've discovered that the problem is in the UDTF:

```
select * from table ( myschema.myfunction() ) where id = '1234'
```

This yields the same "SQL_TABLE_CURSOR not open" error.

Am I trying to do something outside of normal usage?

#### Edit:

Adding an alias gets the query to work, but it took 45 seconds...

```
select t.* from table ( myschema.myfunction() ) t where t.id = '1234'
```

Closer, but still not working right.

---

The function is built like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myschema.myfunction ( ) 
  RETURNS TABLE ( 
  "ID" VARCHAR(255) , 
  ACCOUNTID VARCHAR(255) , 
  CREATEDBYID VARCHAR(255) , 
  CREATEDBY VARCHAR(255) , 
  CREATEDDATE TIMESTAMP , 
  FIELD VARCHAR(255) , 
  ISDELETED VARCHAR(255) , 
  OLDVALUE VARCHAR(5000) , 
  NEWVALUE VARCHAR(5000) )   
  LANGUAGE SQL 
  SPECIFIC myschema.myfunction 
  NOT DETERMINISTIC 
  MODIFIES SQL DATA 
  CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
  CONCURRENT ACCESS RESOLUTION DEFAULT 
  SET OPTION  ALWBLK = *ALLREAD , 
  ALWCPYDTA = *OPTIMIZE , 
  COMMIT = *NONE , 
  DECRESULT = (31, 31, 00) , 
  DYNDFTCOL = *NO , 
  DYNUSRPRF = *USER , 
  SRTSEQ = *HEX   
  RETURN SELECT ID , ACCOUNTID , CREATEDBYID , CREATEDBY , CREATEDDATE , FIELD , ISDELETED , OLDVALUE , NEWVALUE FROM production . myschema . mytable  ;
```

Comment: What is the Db2-server platform ( i-series (as/400),  Z/OS, luw) for DEV and PROD?

Comment: i series, I think 7.3, might be 7.4. Not sure how to check that; I have green screen access but I’m not an IBM guy